# Recursive requirements in Conda environment.yaml

Tags: python, pip, conda

Python pip supports [recursive requirements in the requirements.txt](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html#recursive-requirements). Is this possible with Conda environment.yaml files as well?

What I want to archive is this:
Tensorflow comes in two flavors: with GPU support (tensorflow-gpu) and without GPU support (tensorflow). My intention is to support installation of both flavors.
For pip I create 3 files:

- requirements_base.txt: contains all packages beside Tensorflow
- requirements_gpu.txt: contains a reference to requirements_base.txt (-r flag) and tensorflow-gpu
- requirements_gpu.txt: contains a reference to requirements_base.txt (-r flag) and tensorflow-cpu

This way I can define most of the requirements in a single place, which makes this whole setup much more reliable.

Is the same approach possible with Conda? If not, is there maybe a different way to the same result?

Comment: could you please provide more details about context, so that would be easier to discuss..

Comment: Sure, updated the original question with some more context.